# Mix Switch Managed and Unmanaged. What happen?

Tags: networking, vlan

I would like to ask your opinion on this scenario.

There is a switch "A" is of the Managed type, on its ports the TAG VLAN # 100 is assigned.
Switch "B" is connected to one of these ports; this switch "B" is unmanaged.

On switch "B" there are connected PCs with their own network card identified by TAG # 100 and TAG # 200.

I would expect all PCs on switch "B" with TAG # 100 to be visible to PCs connected to the other ports of switch "A", while the PCs on switch "B" with TAG # 200 are only visible to each other.

In other words, does the unmanaged switch "B" let the tag pass to the managed switch "A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch 'B' doesn't know anything about VLANs, so it will act as an extension of Switch A's port. So if connection between Switch 'A' and Switch 'B' only allows traffic on VLAN100, then VLAN200 will not be visible to Switch 'A' or any of its ports. Switch 'A' will simply discard frame received with tag VLAN200.

Note, tag only takes affect if the port is in trunk mode.